# An error occurred in installing GitLab (install GitLab Shell phase) on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-14.04, gitlab

My server is ubuntu 14.04 (32bit).

GitLab easy installation is provided only for 64bit Ubuntu.

So I follow the guideline for installing GitLab from source. ([documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md))

However, in Install GitLab Shell Phase, an error is occurred like below. (The first line...)

```
# sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:shell:install REDIS_URL=unix:/var/run/redis/redis.sock RAILS_ENV=production SKIP_STORAGE_VALIDATION=true
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.1.2/src/ruby/lib/grpc/grpc_c
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.1.2/src/ruby/lib/grpc/grpc.rb:37:in `require_relative'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.1.2/src/ruby/lib/grpc/grpc.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.1.2/src/ruby/lib/grpc/errors.rb:30:in `require_relative'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.1.2/src/ruby/lib/grpc/errors.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.1.2/src/ruby/lib/grpc.rb:32:in `require_relative'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.1.2/src/ruby/lib/grpc.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/gitaly-0.5.0/ruby/lib/gitaly/commit_services_pb.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/gitaly-0.5.0/ruby/lib/gitaly.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/git/gitlab/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I think it may be ruby's error, but I don't know about ruby...

How I solve this problem?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem currently on Ubuntu 16.04.1. It appears there is some missing source code for the gem to build from, but I don't know what packages are required yet.

Comment: I solved it. Through the log, there is no grpc_c file.

So I installed ruby (same version) to root account. And I installed gem, and grpc.
In the grpc path (may be /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.1.2), there is "grpc_c.so" shared library file. Hence, I copied it and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

Through the log, there is no grpc_c file.

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.1.2/src/ruby/lib/grpc/grpc_c
```

So I installed ruby (same version) to root account.

And I installed gem, and grpc.

In the grpc path,

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/grpc-1.1.2
```

there is "grpc_c.so" shared library file. Hence, I copied it and solved the problem.

Comment: copied it where?